# Amchart 4 Sankey Diagram Node out of range

Tags: amcharts, sankey-diagram

https://codepen.io/aad61404/pen/YRyJxN

https://codepen.io/aad61404/pen/aQvRyz?editors=0010

I am using amcharts 4 Sankey diagram and I want to fix the
node out of range .

I try

```
chart.height = 500;
chart.contentheight = 500;
chart.contentHeight = 500;
chart.innerHeight = 500;
```

It doesn't work . ( the node would  be out of range )

Can I limit the amcharts 4 draw chart in 500 px height ?
How can I achieve the desired effect ?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth the same question was posted to GitHub, the solution provided was:

```js
chart.nodePadding = 1; // default: 20
```

and optionally reduce `chart.nodeMinSize` as well, e.g.

```js
chart.nodeMinSize = 0.01; // default: 0.02
```

Hope this of value to someone.